# variable to pull multiple values from array in javascript (music theory game)

Tags: javascript, arrays

The idea is to have a chord that has three values attached to it. the values are to be stored in an array because the same note will be used in multiple chords.

e.g.

G major = G, B, D

C major = C, E, G

Note that the letter G is used in both chords

Below is an idea of what I want but I don't know what technique I should use. The alert only throws back one value instead of all three.

```
var notes = new Array();
    notes[0] = "A"  ;
    notes[1] = "B" ;
    notes[2] = "C" ;
    notes[3] = "C#" ;
    notes[4] = "D" ;
    notes[5] = "E" ;
    notes[6] = "F#" ;
    notes[7] = "G" ;
    notes[8] = "G#" ;

var Gmajor = notes[7, 1, 4];
var Cmajor = notes[2, 5, 7];


alert(Gmajor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a new array for each multiple chord :

```
var Gmajor = [ notes[7], notes[1], notes[4] ];
```

Answer (score 1):

`notes[7, 1, 4]` is exactly the same as `notes[4]`, if you are interested why, read about the **comma operator**

What you are looking for is:

```
var notes = [ // changed your initialization to use an array literal instead
  "A",  // 0
  "B",  // 1
  "C",  // 2
  "C#", // 3
  "D",  // 4
  "E",  // 5
  "F#", // 6
  "G",  // 7
  "G#"  // 8
];

var Gmajor = [notes[7], notes[1], notes[4]];
var Cmajor = [notes[2], notes[5], notes[7]];
```

If you want it represented as a string, you can do:

```
var GmajorAsString = Gmajor.join(' '); // if you need the array
var GmajorString = notes[7] + ' ' + notes[1] + ' ' + notes[4]; // just string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create function:

```
var notes = new Array();
    notes[0] = "A"  ;
    notes[1] = "B" ;
    notes[2] = "C" ;
    notes[3] = "C#" ;
    notes[4] = "D" ;
    notes[5] = "E" ;
    notes[6] = "F#" ;
    notes[7] = "G" ;
    notes[8] = "G#" ;

var getNotes = function(first, second, third){
    return notes[first] + ' ' + notes[second] + ' ' + notes[third];
}

alert(getNotes(7, 1, 4)); // G B D
```